# ERC1155 : how to find all NFTs information from the event "TransferSingle"

Tags: erc-1155

ERC-1155 is an Ethereum token standard that combines the functionality of previous standards like ERC-20 (for fungible tokens) and ERC-721 (for non-fungible tokens).

ERC-1155 enables the efficient transfer of both fungible and non-fungible tokens within a single transaction — reducing costs and making it more efficient to create & exchange blockchain-based assets.

Taking the example of the function TransferSingle(address, address, address, uint256, uint256), it can be used to transfer both non-fungible tokens and fungible tokens (ERC-20 tokens) according to the definition above.

So my question is , can we find the following informations from transferSingle event:

- is this value NFT ID or fungible token  ( the fourth param of the func)  ?
- if it’s an NFT ID , how to find details about the tokenID ?
- if it's a fungible value , where can we find decimal property ?

E.g:

```
TransferSingle(0x3f62a0a429add9b29feaf1d7c557f285446794af, 0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad, 0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48, 198, 10)
```